# Fullscreen fragment with transparent status bar (programmatically)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an app which is based on single activity and multiple fragments and some fragments needs to show into fullscreen when enters fragment and exit from fullscreen when exit. I am currently using flags to show fullscreen in `Android Kitkat` but its not optimal way i think. I also read `ImmersiveMode` but it's not working in lower Android version. Currently i am using these methods for fullscreen enter and exit.

```
//This method not showing transparent status bar also navigation bar and not showing system icons either
public static void  setFullscreen(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
            int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            boolean isImmersiveAvailable = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
            if (isImmersiveAvailable) {
                flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            }

            activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        } else {
            activity.getWindow()
                    .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }

    public static void exitFullscreen(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
            activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        } else {
            activity.getWindow()
                    .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }


 public static void ShowHideFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen,Context cntx){
        int newUiOptions = 0;
        if (isFullscreen){
            // BEGIN_INCLUDE (get_current_ui_flags)
            // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
            // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
            int uiOptions = ((Activity)cntx).getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
            newUiOptions = uiOptions;
            // END_INCLUDE (get_current_ui_flags)
            // BEGIN_INCLUDE (toggle_ui_flags)
            boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
                    ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
            if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode off. ");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
            }

            // Navigation bar hiding:  Backwards compatible to ICS.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
            }

            // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            }

            // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat.
            // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments the behavior
            // of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  For the purposes of this sample
            // all three flags are being toggled together.
            // Note that there are two immersive mode UI flags, one of which is referred to as "sticky".
            // Sticky immersive mode differs in that it makes the navigation and status bars
            // semi-transparent, and the UI flag does not get cleared when the user interacts with
            // the screen.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            }
            ((Activity)cntx).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);

        }else {
            ((Activity)cntx).getWindow().clearFlags(newUiOptions);

        }
    }
```

These are method we use to enter or exit from fullscreen in fragment with hiding action bar. We use these to entered in fullscreen on `onCreate` and exit on `onPause` but sometimes it fails to show desired result.

We need to know what are the optimal way to show fullscreen fragment on lower API too(KITKAT) and also which are the best way to hide toolbar when showing fullscreen because our code `((AppCompatActivity)Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().hide();`
 throws nullpointerexception sometimes.

Our issue:

1. Show fullscreen fragment with transparent status bar and drawing system icon over fullscreen fragment and transparent navigation bar.
2. Hiding and showing toolbar with method which safe to call without getting `NullpointerExepection`
3. We can target android Kitkat as lowest android version.

Fragment Fullscreen example with system icons and transparent navigation bar.
[image]

**Update:** I set `IMMERSIVE` mode on my fragment `onResume` and reset it back at `onStop` by these method.

```
 private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        ((AppCompatActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().hide();

    }

    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        ((AppCompatActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
```

It shows my fragment in fullscreen with status bar hidden (that's not what i want) and my fragments belong to `Navigation Drawer`. when i press back button from fullscreen fragment it shows my status bar over toolbar in previous fragment.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by creating a method which clears desired flags at `onStop` and add flags at `onResume`

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        App_Functions.transparentStatusBar(getActivity(),true,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        App_Functions.transparentStatusBar(getActivity(),false,false);

    }
```

if i want to show transparent statusbar but navigation bar should be same then i use true in first parameters of method and for clearing that flag just use false. Same way i am using true for complete fullscreen and false for clearing fullscreen flags

```
public static void transparentStatusBar(Activity activity, boolean isTransparent, boolean fullscreen) {
        if (isTransparent){
            activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
            ((AppCompatActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(activity)).getSupportActionBar().hide();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                defaultStatusBarColor = activity.getWindow().getStatusBarColor();
                activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                // FOR TRANSPARENT NAVIGATION BAR
                //activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
                activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                Log.d(TAG,"Setting Color Transparent "+Color.TRANSPARENT+ " Default Color "+defaultStatusBarColor);
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Setting Color Trans "+Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                }
            }

        }else {
            if (fullscreen){
                View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
                int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

            }else {
                ((AppCompatActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(activity)).getSupportActionBar().show();
                activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
                    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
                    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(defaultStatusBarColor);

                }else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                    }
                }

            }
                    }
    }
```

Please feel free to recommend better way to use this method across all platform.

Answer (score 1):

### How to handle the toolbar from fragment?

Where to put the toolbar is highly opinionated. But I recommend you to put the toolbar in each fragment xml file rather than keeping one toolbar for the whole application in the Activity xml file.  [See this](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_plant_detail.xml) sample app by Google, they are also placing the AppbarLayout and toolbar per Fragment rather than keeping it in the activity layout file.

So if you place the toolbar with in the fragment, you can easily hide/show it from the fragment without the fear of getting null pointer exceptions.

So your activity xml file will simply contain the NavHost Fragment only. So the whole screen will be managed by the currently visible Fragment :)

### How to get the transparent statusbar for older API levels?

Devices below kitkat would not support transparent statusbar feature. Kitkat supports transluent statusbar, not transparent. So you can use transparent statusbar for API level lollipop or above. If the device version is below lollipop, ignore it as the platform does not support the feature. So rest of my answer assumes you want to achieve transparent status bar when the device version is lollipop or above.

### Well then, How to get transparent status-bar for lollipop and above for selected fragments?

We need to create a custom NavHostFragment. This is required because, during fragment transitions, multiple fragment's view hierarchies can be added at the same time. If one consumes window insets, the other might not be laid out properly. To workaround that, we need to make sure we dispatch the insets to all children, regardless of how they are consumed.

```
class DispatchInsetsNavHostFragment : NavHostFragment() {



 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->               
                (v as? ViewGroup)?.forEach { child ->
                    child.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(insets)
                }
                insets
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wrap your nav host fragment with a Framelayout as shown below and put **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"**

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navHostContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:name="com.yourdomain.app.DispatchInsetsNavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Set the following flags to the navHostContainer which we defined above, from your MainActivity class `onCreate` method after `setContentView`.

```
   val navHostContainer: FrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.navHostContainer)
    navHostContainer.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    // Make the content ViewGroup ignore insets so that it does not use the default padding
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        navHostContainer.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(NoopWindowInsetsListener)
    }
```

Here is the `NoopWindowInsetsListener`

```
object NoopWindowInsetsListener : View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener {
    override fun onApplyWindowInsets(v: View, insets: WindowInsets): WindowInsets {
        return insets
    }
}
```

Thats all, from now on, your fragments has the complete ownership to the statusbar area. Your views will be drawn behind the transparent status bar. For some fragments, you may not want the statusbar to overlap your content, for those fragments, simply put **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** to your root layout in the Fragment xml file.

### How to set custom statusbar color for some Fragments?

Use the `app:statusBarBackground` attribute of `CoordinatorLayout` with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

That's all. Happy coding :)

Comment: Can you please change it into Java

Comment: don't  worry, you can use those kt files with in your java project.

Comment: Sunflower app use only single `toolbar` for whole app and for it's main activity they have static fragment for navhost.. You solution is nice but for this i need to change whole app layout files.

Comment: @androidXP If you want to keep the toolbar in the activity xml and want to show/hide, then you can make use of the activity ViewModel class. Then put a Livedata variable in the ViewModel to indicate the toolbar visibility, and observe its value from the Activity class. Then from any fragment under the same Activity, you can easily get the ViewModel and set the visibility. Since the LiveData objects are lifecycle aware, you will not get null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

1- in style xml file change AppTheme parent to NoActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

2- use this method in your activity for transparent statusBar

```
private void hideStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
    }
}
```

3- match_parent frameLayout tag in your activity_main(xml) for full screen the fragment